# Can anyone please guide how to pull private images from Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

kubectl create secret docker-registry private-registry-key --docker-username="devopsrecipes" --docker-password="xxxxxx" --docker-email="username@example.com" --docker-server="https://index.docker.io/v1/"
secret "private-registry-key" created

This command is used for accessing private docker repos.

As referenced: http://blog.shippable.com/kubernetes-tutorial-how-to-pull-private-docker-image-pod

But, not able to pull the image.

When tried to access ="https://index.docker.io/v1/"
It is giving page not found error.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 4):

You also need to refer the *imagePullSecrets* in the pod / deployment spec you create:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: <your-private-image>
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: private-registry-key
```

Read more about *imagePullSecrets* [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/).

Comment: Yeah, I added the below line in my deployment created by kubectl edit deployment command.But still now working
imagePullSecrets:
  - name: private-registry-key

Comment: Can you please post your YAML file for better understanding? Ideally, @Abhishek answer should work.

Comment: Use `kubectl describe pod` to see the exact reason why its not able to pull the image. Also check manually if the image is valid and present in the docker repo.

Answer (score 0):

I Just tried creating the same on my cluster.

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry private-registry-key --docker-username="xx" --docker-password="xx" --docker-email="xx" --docker-server="https://index.docker.io/v1/"
```

Output:

> secret/private-registry-key created

My Yaml file looks like

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: vaibhavjain882/ubuntubase:latest
    command: ["sleep", "30"]
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: private-registry-key


NAME          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
private-reg   1/1     Running   0          35s
```

***Note: Just verify, if you are passing the correct docker image name. In my case its "vaibhavjain882/ubuntubase:latest"***

Comment: When I tried today, the first approach of passing the config file wrking.Not the second approach of passing credentials from command line.

I am passing --docker-username as uday1kiran (without @gmail.com) is that expected format?

Comment: Try login from browser and use the same credentials.